# Why can't I update statement in SQLite?

Tags: iphone, sqlite

Can anyone help me with this code snippet:

```
-(void) updateData:(NSString*)value1:(NSString*)value2
 {
    sqlite3* database;
    databaseName = @"AppDB.sqlite";
    NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    databasePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];

    int databaseReturnCode = sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database);
    if(databaseReturnCode == SQLITE_OK) {

    sqlite3_stmt *updateStmt;
    const char *sql = "update PersonalInfo Set FirstName = ?,LastName = ? Where id = '1'";
    //sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &updateStmt, NULL);
    sqlite3_prepare(database, sql, -1, &updateStmt,nil);

    sqlite3_bind_text(updateStmt, 1, [value1 UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(updateStmt, 2, [value2 UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);


    printf( "Update PersonalInfo| error or not an error? :  %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(database) ); 

    while(sqlite3_step(updateStmt) == SQLITE_ROW) 
    {
        NSString *aFirstName  = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(updateStmt, 1)];
        NSString *aLastName  = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(updateStmt, 2)];


        ProfileInfo *profile = [[ProfileInfo alloc]initWithFirstName:(NSString*)aFirstName LastName:(NSString*)aLastName];
        [personalInfo addObject:profile];
        [profile release];
    }
        sqlite3_reset(updateStmt);
        sqlite3_finalize(updateStmt);
    }

}
    sqlite3_close(database);    
}
```

It doesn't enter the while loop.
 But if I remove the while loop and 
 enclose the code in a try-catch block and I get this exception:

```
+[NSString stringWithUTF8String:]: NULL cString
```

Comment: It is not the cause of this (or any other) problem, but there is no point in resetting the statement with `sqlite3_reset` before destroying it with `sqlite3_finalize`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `sqlite_step` while-loop is inappropriate for an update statement.

From the documentation at sqlite.org:

> **sqlite3_step()**     This routine is used to evaluate a prepared statement
>   that has been previously created by the sqlite3_prepare() interface.
>   The statement is evaluated up to the point where the first row of
>   results are available. To advance to the second row of results, invoke
>   sqlite3_step() again. Continue invoking sqlite3_step() until the
>   statement is complete. **Statements that do not return results (ex:
>   INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statements) run to completion on a single
>   call to sqlite3_step()**.

Check your return value of `sqlite_step`. It should be something like `SQLITE_DONE` rather than `SQLITE_ROW`.